# Parse Cloud Code GeoPoint

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have a Parse App which has two basic objects.  The first object "User" has a property called "location" which stores a GeoPoint.

The second object is "Sighting" which has a "location" property with a GeoPoint.

In my cloud code I have sucessfuly introduced an aftersave function on the "Sighting" object so that a push notification is sent to everybody once a sighting has been saved.

However what I am trying to achieve is only sending those users within a certain range.

I have found query.withinKilometeres but I cannot understand how to compare all User."Locations" and take the saved object "Location" as the base.  Thereafter send all returned users a push.

The cloud code is totally alien to me so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 0):

The target of push is _Installation.
In your question, you should maintain a pointer 'user' for related currentUser of the device.

```
//afterSave of Sighting
var sighting = request.object;
//means created, not update
if(!sight.existed()){
    var location = sighting.get('location');
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    //1 for example
    userQuery.withinKilometeres('location', 1);

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.matchesQuery('user', userQuery);

    Parse.Push.send({
        where:query,
        data:{
            alert: "this is msg",
            title: "this is title" 
        }
    },{useMasterKey:true})
    .then(function(){
        console.log('push done');
    }, function(error){
        console.error(error);
    });

}
```

There are a limitation of matchesQuery. In this case, you cannot send more than 1000 user (to get related installations).

So I suggest you put location info in _Installation, and it more make sense(Your user may have multiple device, but User cannot split to 2 places)

Comment: Wow thank you. Parse cloud is more difficult than I anticipated so would this effectively send a push to every installation within 1km of the sighting location ?

Comment: The performance is depends on your design, and the result sizes. The query performance is one of the key point of push.(But sometimes parse.com delays may 1~30 min to push)